# Variable used into a PSQL query

Tags: python, pandasql

I have a problem with my code python, i'm using Pandasql, and what i want is to use my (enddate) in a query so:

enddate = pd.to_datetime(datetime.today()).date()

q2 = """SELECT * FROM res_q1 t1 where t1.JOURS = (enddate)  """
res_q2 = psql.sqldf(q2, locals())

Can you help me plz!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add it with formatting, e.g.

```py
from datetime import datetime

end_date = pd.to_datetime(datetime.today()).date()

q2 = """SELECT * FROM res_q1 t1 where t1.JOURS = ({}) """.format(end_date)
res_q2 = psql.sqldf(q2, locals())
```

Hope this helps :)